# Is this a valid definition for vertical asymptote?

Tags: definition

> $x=a$ is a vertical asymptote of the graph of a function $f$ if for every $\mu \gt 0$ there exists $\delta \gt 0$ such that for all $x$ where $|x-a| \lt \delta$, this implies $|f(x)| \gt \mu$.

Comment: If you write "where $0 < |x-a|<\delta$" [to exclude input $x=a$] then it looks OK.